# jQuery response() function doesn't return any results because of the variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The problem I encountered is I can't get any results from the jQuery UI Autocomplete form because of the variable scope. Let me show you.

```
// TAKE A CLOSE LOOK AT THIS METHOD
select: function(e, ui) {

$('#instant-search').text(ui.item.label);
$("#search").autocomplete("option", "source",
  function(request, response) {
    getAutocompleteResults(function(d) {
      // DOESN'T WORK response(d);
    });
    // WORKS BUT IT SHOULD BE A DYNAMIC ARRAY FROM THE "D" OBJECT
    // response(["anarchism", "anarchist black cross", "black rose (symbolism)", "communist symbolism", "political symbolism"]);
  });

$("#search").autocomplete("search", ui.item.label);
```

In order to return results I have to use a function `response([...]);` outside the `getAutocompleteResults(function(d) { ... });` function.

However, the source should be dynamic and not like the static array. In other words:

The function `response(d);` should return an object, which contains a few properties (title, value, extract). I have to access them by using `response(d);`, however, this function doesn't work inside `getAutocompleteResults(function(d) { ... });` function. How can I achieve this?

There is a small snippet of code, however, the main problem is the `select` method. You can find this in the middle of the whole code block. I commented it out.

```js
$(function() {
  $("html").removeClass("no-js");
  var autocompleteResults = [{
    title: [],
    extract: [],
    pageId: []
  }];

  var capitalizeFirstLetter = function(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  };

  var changeText2 = function(e) {
    var request = $("input").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $("#instant-search").text(request);

    var getAutocompleteResults = function(callback) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrlimit=6&prop=extracts&origin=*&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&gsrsearch=" +
          $("#instant-search").text(),
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".loading").show();
        },
        success: function(d) {
          $(".loading").hide();
          autocompleteResults[0].title = [];
          autocompleteResults[0].extract = [];
          autocompleteResults[0].pageId = [];

          if (d.hasOwnProperty("query")) {
            if (d.query.hasOwnProperty("pages")) {
              $.each(d.query.pages, function(i) {
                autocompleteResults[0].title.push(d.query.pages[i].title);

                autocompleteResults[0].extract.push(d.query.pages[i].extract);
                autocompleteResults[0].pageId.push(d.query.pages[i].pageid);
              });
            }
          }

          if (!autocompleteResults[0].length) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").hide();
          }


          autocompleteResults[0].title.sort(function(a, b) {
            var nameA = a.toUpperCase();
            var nameB = b.toUpperCase();
            if (nameA < nameB) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (nameA > nameB) {
              return 1;
            }

            return 0;
          });

          autocompleteResults[0].title = autocompleteResults[0].title.map(
            function(i) {
              return i.toLowerCase();
            }
          );

          callback(autocompleteResults[0]);
        },
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    };

    $("#search").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        getAutocompleteResults(function(d) {
          var results = [],
            filteredAutocompleteResults = [];

          filteredAutocompleteResults = d.title.filter(function(i) {
            return (
              i !=
              $("#instant-search")
              .text()
              .toLowerCase()
            );
          });

          for (var i = 0; i < d.title.length; i++) {
            results[i] = {
              label: filteredAutocompleteResults[i],
              extract: d.extract[i],
              pageId: d.pageId[i]
            };
          }

          if (results.length == 5) {
            response(results);
          } else {
            response(results.slice(0, 5));
          }
        });
      },
      response: function() {
        if ($("#instant-search").text()) {
          $("table").css("display", "table");
          $(".wikisearch-container").css("margin-top", 100);
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        if (!$(".ui-autocomplete").is(":visible")) {
          $(".ui-autocomplete").show();
        }
      },
      appendTo: ".input",
      focus: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      delay: 0,












      // TAKE A CLOSE LOOK AT THIS METHOD
      select: function(e, ui) {

        $('#instant-search').text(ui.item.label);
        $("#search").autocomplete("option", "source",
          function(request, response) {
            getAutocompleteResults(function(d) {
              // DOESN'T WORK response(d);
            });
            // WORKS BUT IT SHOULD BE A DYNAMIC ARRAY FROM THE "D" OBJECT
            // response(["anarchism", "anarchist black cross", "black rose (symbolism)", "communist symbolism", "political symbolism"]);
          });

        $("#search").autocomplete("search", ui.item.label);










        // EVERYTHING SHOULD BE FINE BELOW THIS LINE

        if ($(".search-results").css("opacity") != 1) {
          $(".search-results h4").text(capitalizeFirstLetter(ui.item.label));
          $(".search-results p").text(ui.item.extract);
          $(".search-results a").prop(
            "href",
            "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" + ui.item.pageId
          );
          $(".search-results").css("opacity", 1);
        } else if (
          $(".search-results h4")
          .text()
          .toLowerCase() != ui.item.label
        ) {
          $(".search-results").css("opacity", 0);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(".search-results h4").text(capitalizeFirstLetter(ui.item.label));
            $(".search-results p").text(ui.item.extract);
            $(".search-results a").prop(
              "href",
              "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" + ui.item.pageId
            );
            $(".search-results").css("opacity", 1);
          }, 500);
        }
      },
      create: function() {
        $(this).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
          return $("<li>")
            .append(
              '<div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><div class="autocomplete-first-field"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="autocomplete-second-field three-dots">' +
              item.label +
              "</div></div>"
            )
            .appendTo(ul);
        };
      }
    });
  };


  var changeText1 = function(e) {
    if (
      /[-a-z0-90áãâäàéêëèíîïìóõôöòúûüùçñ!@#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\s\/]+/gi.test(
        String.fromCharCode(e.which)
      )
    ) {
      $("input").on("keypress", changeText2);
    }


    // DONT TOUCH THIS AREA, IT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH THE PROBLEM
    var getInputSelection = function(input) {
      var start = 0,
        end = 0;
      input.focus();
      if (
        typeof input.selectionStart == "number" &&
        typeof input.selectionEnd == "number"
      ) {
        start = input.selectionStart;
        end = input.selectionEnd;
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        if (range) {
          var inputRange = input.createTextRange();
          var workingRange = inputRange.duplicate();
          var bookmark = range.getBookmark();
          inputRange.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
          workingRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", inputRange);
          end = workingRange.text.length;
          workingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", inputRange);
          start = workingRange.text.length;
        }
      }
      return {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        length: end - start
      };
    };

    switch (e.key) {
      case "Backspace":
      case "Delete":
        e = e || window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        var deleteKey = keyCode == 46;
        var sel, deletedText, val;
        val = this.value;
        sel = getInputSelection(this);
        if (sel.length) {
          // 0 kai paprastai trini po viena o 1 ar daugiau kai select su pele trini
          $("#instant-search").text(
            val.substr(0, sel.start) + val.substr(sel.end)
          );
        } else {
          $("#instant-search").text(
            val.substr(0, deleteKey ? sel.start : sel.start - 1) +
            val.substr(deleteKey ? sel.end + 1 : sel.end)
          );
        }
        break;
      case "Enter":
        if ($("#instant-search").text()) {
          console.log("Redirecting...");
        }
        break;
    }

    if (!$("#instant-search").text()) {
      $("table, .ui-autocomplete").hide();
      $(".wikisearch-container").css("margin-top", "");
    }

    if (
      $(".ui-menu-item-wrapper").hasClass("ui-state-active") &&
      (e.key == "ArrowRight" || e.key == "ArrowLeft")
    ) {
      $(".ui-autocomplete").autocomplete(""); // Error metas console ir taip neturėtų būti bet nežinau kaip padaryti kad pasirinkus elementą su <-- ar --> nepadarytų tik vieno rezultato todėl paliekam laikinai ;)
    }
  };

  $("input").on("keydown", changeText1);

  $("input").on("input", function(e) {
    $("#instant-search").text($("#search").val());
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url("http://www.part.lt/img/96816a00ec1fb87adc4ca8a04365b2b5719.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 100%;
}

.v-container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.v-content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.input input#search {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  color: #4f5b66;
  padding: 0 15px;
  outline: none;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  top: auto !important;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
}

.autocomplete-first-field {
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.autocomplete-second-field {
  width: 85%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.three-dots {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color: #ffc800;
  color: #fff;
}

table td,
.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: left;
}

.ui-menu-item,
table {
  cursor: pointer;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.search-results {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-left: 5px solid #0ebeff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.search-results h4,
.search-results p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-results a {
  color: #0ebeff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.search-results a:before {
  background-color: #0ebeff;
}

.wikisearch-container {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Loading animation */

@keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 9.5px;
  right: 15px;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

.lds-eclipse {
  -webkit-animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-shadow: 0.08rem 0 0 #0ebeff;
}

@media (max-width: 71.875em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 75%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 17.96875em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<html class="no-js">
<div class="v-container">
  <div class="v-content text-center">
    <div class="wikisearch-container">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
        <div class="loading">
          <div class="lds-eclipse"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td class="fa fa-search">
              <td id="instant-search" class="three-dots"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="search-results">
        <h4></h4>
        <p></p>
        <a target="_blank">Click here for more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**
After some changes, the results are shown, however, before the ajax call. How can I use `response()` only after the ajax was successfully completed (tried using `success` callback, didn't work :()?

Full project code: https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/zRONyw?editors=0010.

---

Here you can see step by step how it looks like:

1. How it looks like when you just reloaded the page:
   [image]
2. Let's try entering "a":
   [image]
3. We've got some results. Ok, let's try to click on the "anarchist symbolism" element:
   [image]
4. Results should look like "anarchist symbolism" search. However, it returns the result of the "a" search. What if we pressed "fraktur" element?
   [image]
5. Now it shows our previous search "anarchist symbolism" results. However, it should return elements of the "fraktur" search.

**EDIT 2**
I've fixed many things and removed some really non sense things from my code. However, the situation with the ajax call is still the same.

https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/pazppP?editors=0110

Any ideas?

**EDIT 3**
Fixed ajax lag (now the ajax request will be sent only after the previous ajax call).

https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/JpPLON?editors=0110

Comment: It would be better to `return` your data from `getAutocompleteResults()`. This way you can send the data to `response()`.

Comment: Can you show me by the example, please?

Comment: Currently, your example is overly complex and there are a number of HTML syntax errors and elements that do not make a lot of sense. I have this so far which is cleaner, but also not working as you described: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vr6gv2aw/1/

Comment: `<html class="no-js">`, `<button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>` really doesn't make sense here because there is no selector in the CSS.

Comment: I'm new to JS stuff so yeah thank you for saying that. Can you please say what doesnt makr any sense, I really want to understand each part of my code and how to optimize it?

Comment: @Twisty, so if I return the value, then I could use it in the response() and it would work in my example?

Comment: @Twisty I've checked your example and it returns a bunch of values from the object to the console. I'm not exactly sure what you meant by this example :)

Comment: The example also returns the same data to `response()`. This example http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple helps show the use of `source` as a function. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: But it's using the same technique as I do. I know how to use `function(request, response) { ... });`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to first fix a few things in your Ajax call. We then collect the results and build an array that should be returned to `response()`. This will populate the AutoComplete.

First we will examine the HTML. There was some closing tags missing.

**HTML**

```
<div class="v-container">
  <div class="v-content text-center">
    <div class="wikisearch-container">
      <div class="input ui-front">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
        <div class="loading">
          <div class="lds-eclipse"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td class="fa fa-search"></td>
            <td id="instant-search" class="three-dots"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="search-results">
        <h4></h4>
        <p></p>
        <a target="_blank">Click here for more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the `table` and it's cells all have the proper closing tags now.

I didn't make any changes to your CSS or Style.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var capitalizeFirstLetter = function(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  };
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var results = [];
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
        data: {
          format: "json",
          action: "query",
          generator: "search",
          gsrlimit: 6,
          prop: "extracts|pageimages",
          origin: "*",
          pilimit: "max",
          exintro: false,
          explaintext: false,
          exsentences: 1,
          gsrsearch: request.term
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".loading").show();
        },
        success: function(d) {
          $(".loading").hide();
          if (d.query.pages) {
            $.each(d.query.pages, function(k, v) {
              console.log(k, v.title, v.extract, v.pageid);
              results.push({
                label: v.title,
                value: "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" + v.pageid,
                title: v.title,
                extract: v.extract,
                pageId: v.pageid
              });
            });
            response(results);
          }
        },
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
      response(results);
    },
    close: function() {
      if (!$(".ui-autocomplete").is(":visible")) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").show();
      }
    },
    focus: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    },
    delay: 0,
    select: function(e, ui) {
      if ($(".search-results").css("opacity") != 1) {
        $(".search-results h4").text(capitalizeFirstLetter(ui.item.label));
        $(".search-results p").text(ui.item.extract);
        $(".search-results a").prop(
          "href",
          ui.item.value
        );
        $(".search-results").css("opacity", 1);
      } else if (
        $(".search-results h4")
        .text()
        .toLowerCase() != ui.item.label
      ) {
        $(".search-results").css("opacity", 0);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".search-results h4").text(capitalizeFirstLetter(ui.item.label));
          $(".search-results p").text(ui.item.extract);
          $(".search-results a").prop(
            "href",
            ui.item.value
          );
          $(".search-results").css("opacity", 1);
        }, 500);
      }
      return false;
    }
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var $item = $("<li>");
    var $wrap = $("<div>").appendTo($item);
    var $field1 = $("<div>", {
      class: "autocomplete-first-field"
    }).appendTo($wrap);
    $("<i>", {
      class: "fa fa-search",
      "aria-hidden": true
    }).appendTo($field1);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "autocomplete-second-field three-dots"
    }).html(item.label).appendTo($wrap);
    return $item.appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

There was a lot of things to fix and improve.

Let's start with the Ajax. You're making a call to a MediaWiki API and expecting some results. When the call would come back, it would generate warnings about `pilimit`. Digging into the API docs, this is a parameter specific to the `pageimages` properties call. To fix this, the `prop` value had to be `extracts|pageimages`. Now I get a clean set of results.

You can see I broke out the data so that I could more easily make changes and see what parameters I was sending to the API. Nothing wrong with your method, I just find this a lot easier to work with.

This is all happening inside `.autocomplete()` when we are populating the `source`. When we use `function` as a `source`, it has to follow a few guidelines:

- we pass a `request` and `response` in
- results must be in an array
- the array can contain objects, as long as they contain at least `{ label, value }`
- our results array must be passed to `response` function.

A brief example:

```
$(selector).autocomplete({
  source: function(req, resp){
    var q = req.term;
    // The Request is an object that contains 1 index: term
    // request.term will contain the content of our search
    var results = [];
    // An array to store the results
    $.getJSON("myapi.php", {query: q}, function(data){
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
        // iterate over the result data and populate our result array
        results.push({
          label: data.name,
          value: data.url
        });
        resp(results);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

You can sort or filter the results all you like; as long as you pass them to `response` in the end.

With your `focus` and `select` callbacks, you want to return `false`. This is discussed more here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

We also see a good example of rendering the menu item. I switched over to making jQuery objects versus raw HTML. You do what works best for you.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vr6gv2aw/4/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, I didn't read it until the end and have a question: why did u put a class `ui-front` to the `<div class="input">` element? I can't say how much you helped me with JS stuff. I think it's your next answer to my problem. The first time you also helped me very much. Thank you!! :) I really appreciate what you're doing.

Comment: I removed the `pimax`, so the part `extracts|pageimages` became `extracts`. I didn't even need this parameter, sorry.

Comment: Also, can I use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`? Do these two have a difference in jQuery Autocomplete? The `return false;` would skip anything after it so I don't think it's a good option for the `select` event.

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis you can use `.preventDefault()` yet `return false` is more definitive. `ui-front` helps define where to append the menu. *When the value is null, the parents of the input field will be checked for a class of `ui-front`. If an element with the `ui-front` class is found, the menu will be appended to that element. Regardless of the value, if no element is found, the menu will be appended to the body.*

Comment: Also, on the element in the autocomplete click, a menu shouldn't close (so I commented out the  `close` event. Another problem is when you click it, the values of the list should also change.

Comment: And should I use both `e.preventDefault(); return false;` or only one is enough like `return false;`?

Comment: `return false` should be enough. Depends on what you're doing.

Comment: YES! I found a solution!

Comment: However (hehe :)), the results are shown before the ajax call is done. Using `response();` in the success callback didn't work. What can I do here?

Comment: can you please check my edit? I've also included my project code on codepen.